# Can't link to JDK10 in Javadoc comments

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, java-10

After upgrading from Java 9 to 10, links to the JDK no longer work when generating documentation with the Javadoc tool (e.g., for a file importing `java.util.Optional`, `{@link Optional}` renders as `Optional` instead of as [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html); same issue with `@see`, `@param`, `@return`, and anywhere else you normally see Javadoc links).

I have a simple modularized project, and I'm using Maven with the Javadoc plugin (`source` and `target` options set to `10` in the `configuration` section for the compiler plugin). My understanding is that by default it passes `-link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/` to the Javadoc tool. It's also my understanding that, historically, the Javadoc tool expected a text file named `package-list` to be present at the URL where it was told to find external docs. Java 8 [has one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/package-list). Java 9 [has one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/package-list). Java 10 [does not](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/package-list) (404 error). Apparently, the Javadoc tool now outputs a text file named `element-list` instead of `package-list` for modularized projects, but it seems like that [isn't provided](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/element-list) either (nor for [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/element-list), but it is available for early-access builds of [Java 11](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/element-list)).

Generating Javadoc through IntelliJ with the option `Link to JDK documentation` enabled produces the same result. It says it's passing `-link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/` to `javadoc.exe`, and it reports `javadoc: error - Error fetching URL: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/`. Despite the error, it does output the Javadoc, but as with Maven, no JDK links are present.

How is this supposed to work? Did Oracle screw up when they put the JDK docs online?

The relevant bits of my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1</version> <!--update dependency for Java 10 compatibility-->
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Output of `mvn -version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T12:49:05-07:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 10, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: @JacobG. The docs themselves are present and working fine. The problem occurs when trying to link to them using Javadoc tags.

Comment: Where?  The links on my question are dead at the moment.  I did just find this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/toc.htm

Comment: When Java 10 was released three days ago, the docs moved from [download.java.net](https://download.java.net/java/jdk10/docs/api/) to [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/).

Comment: 1. What command did you execute to successfully generate those docs? 2. Did you not face an [NPE while executing the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460751/execution-attach-javadocs-of-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-javadoc-plugin)?

Comment: @nullpointer `mvn clean test javadoc:javadoc` (I have some JUnit 5 tests, and I'm using version 2.19.1 of the Maven Surefire plugin). No exceptions, build succeeds. `mvn clean package` also works fine for me. I've added the output of `mvn -version` to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @gdejohn Possibly I met another consequent error scenario which is fixed for 3.0.1. But I agree, the generation of the doc links seems broken as compared to Java-9. Also agreeing to the point that even the latest `3.0.1-SNAPSHOT` for maven-javadoc-plugin I used to test the previously linked question doesn't consist of the `package-list` for 10 either. Some instinct of mine just keep pitching in and points me to the direction of [Removal of the old standard doclet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html#JDK-8177511) which could be impacting the plugin.

Comment: I guess also to the fact that... *My understanding is that by default it passes -link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api to the Javadoc tool.It's also my understanding that in the past, the Javadoc tool expected a text file named package-list to be present at the URL where it was told to find external docs* .... Please note a change in Java10, [It should be an error if javadoc cannot access the contents of aURL for -link.](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8180019)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two parts to this.

1. In JDK 10, the format and name of the file have changed, to better support modules. The new name is "element-list" and the change in format allows the javadoc tool to know what modules are present in an API as well as what packages.
2. The copy of the API that is posted at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/overview-summary.html seems to be blocking the "element-list" file, giving a 404. That needs to be investigated and fixed.

Note that you will need to use a JDK 10 version of javadoc to point to the JDK 10 API. The latest version of the tool understands both element-list (for docs about modules) and package-list (for docs about packages (i.e. no modules)).

Comment: I was able to work around the problem with a local `package-file` using the `-linkoffline` option for `javadoc.exe` via the Maven Javadoc plugin, but when I tried with an `element-list`, it didn't work (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49482502/464306)). Any idea why that is? `mvn -version` says it's using Java 10.

Comment: We are investigating the 404.

Comment: I'm also curious why there's no [`element-list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/element-list) for Java 9 (404 error), but there is a [`package-list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/package-list).

Comment: The problem that was causing .../element-list to give 404 has been fixed.

Comment: Now that `element-list` is available, the problem is fixed from Oracle's end. But there's still something going wrong with Maven. The Javadoc plugin configuration option [`detectJavaApiLink`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#detectJavaApiLink) (enabled by default) is supposed to figure out the JDK Javadoc URL for you, but I only get JDK links in the generated Javadoc if I explicitly provide the URL with the plugin option [`links`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#links).

Answer (score 10):

My workaround for the moment is to point `javadoc.exe` at a local `package-list` using the [`offlineLinks`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#offlineLinks) option of the Maven Javadoc plugin (which corresponds to the [`linkoffline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javadoc.htm#GUID-9D532574-1CDB-4D30-99F3-A308DCAEE55F__STANDARDDOCLETOPTIONS-9A14BD97) option of the Javadoc tool). I added the following to the `configuration` section for the plugin:

```
<detectJavaApiLink>false</detectJavaApiLink>
<offlineLinks>
    <offlineLink>
        <url>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/${maven.compiler.release}/docs/api/</url>
        <location>${project.basedir}</location>
    </offlineLink>
</offlineLinks>
```

And I added `<maven.compiler.release>10</maven.compiler.release>` to the `properties` section of my `pom.xml` so that I could use `${maven.compiler.release}` in the value for the `url`. (That makes the `source` and `target` compiler options redundant, but IntelliJ doesn't seem to understand `release` when importing Maven projects, so I kept them.)

I created a text file named `package-list` (no file extension) and put it in the root directory of the project (hence `${project.basedir}` for the `location`, which is where it will look for `package-list`). That file looks like this:

```
java.lang
java.util
java.util.concurrent
java.util.function
java.util.stream
```

It only needs the packages that you're trying to link to. I also tried naming the file `element-list` and following the format that `javadoc.exe` uses for modularized projects, like so:

```
module:java.base
java.lang
java.util
java.util.concurrent
java.util.function
java.util.stream
```

But that didn't work (Javadoc successfully generated, but no JDK links, as before). It complained that it couldn't find `package-list`.

So, once again, the relevant bits of the `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>10</maven.compiler.release> <!--release makes source and target-->
    <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source> <!--redundant, but IntelliJ doesn't-->
    <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target> <!--use release when importing-->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1</version> <!--update dependency for Java 10 compatibility-->
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <detectJavaApiLink>false</detectJavaApiLink>
                <offlineLinks>
                    <offlineLink>
                        <url>https://docs.oracle.com/javase/${maven.compiler.release}/docs/api/</url>
                        <location>${project.basedir}</location>
                    </offlineLink>
                </offlineLinks>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: I would also suggest at the same time to raise it to [maven issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MJAVADOC) so that they can either - further raise it to JDK and get to know why package-list is missing from Java10 or - provide an alternate solution if this was planned to be changing from JDK release.

Answer (score 6):

...Maven committer here.

Appropriate bits have been added to Maven Javadoc Plugin in master already, but that won't help due to a bug in `javadoc(1)` in Java 11. See [MJAVADOC-561](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-561) for details. The broken links can only be fixed by Oracle.

Edit: The fix is scheduled for Java 11.0.2 by Oracle.