# Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar failed with Java10

Tags: java, maven, maven-javadoc-plugin, java-10

Following the link [Upgrade to Java 10 breaks links in Javadoc comments to JDK packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49457896/upgrading-to-java-10-broke-links-in-javadoc-comments-to-jdk-packages) and trying to reproduce the same while I could set the build configuration to :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>6.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalOptions>
                    <additionalOption>-html5</additionalOption>
                </additionalOptions>
                <nodeprecatedlist>true</nodeprecatedlist>
                <notree>true</notree>
                <quiet>true</quiet>
                <show>public</show>
                <splitindex>true</splitindex>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

***Note*** - This works successfully with Java-9 on executing **`mvn clean verify -X`**.

On the other hand, if I change the source and target to 10(Java-10), the build fails with a `PluginExecutionException` caused by `NullPointerException` with  following stack trace :

```
Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar failed.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution attach-javadocs of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar failed.
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast (SystemUtils.java:1626)
```

Is the Javadoc plugin not compatible with Java-10? Or am I missing some configuration there?

Version details in case required -

> ```
> Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-25T01:19:05+05:30)
> Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.3/libexec
> Java version: 10, vendor: Oracle Corporation
> Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.jdk/Contents/Home
> Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: US-ASCII
> OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
> ```

Comment: Do you have chance to test a snapshot? I have made one and checked against your example and it works. But would you please recheck on your site please: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/3.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-javadoc-plugin-3.0.1-20180324.093847-18.jar  ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Verified. Works with the `3.0.1-SNAPSHOT` from *url:http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/*. Would be good if you can update with an answer on what changes fixed it and what was wrong with the current version.

Comment: Thanks to you @nullpoint for verifying it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was related to an [issue in commons-lang](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1365) which caused the issue as you can see in the stack trace.

This has been fixed in current state of development [`maven-javadoc-plugin`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-517). This needs to be released.

Comment: Explicitly stating a newer version directly in the <plugin> helps. 
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is to add

```
              <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
              </configuration>
```

to the maven-javadoc-plugin part in pom.xml

Comment: Of course, the intention with my question was to resolve the error and not ignore it.

Comment: it worked in my case... so i thought it might help u